# How to turn off trash?

Tags: trash

I don't believe in Trash Bin and when I delete something I want it to be gone forever, how to turn off the Trash?

P.S. When I delete files from the console do they also go to Trash?

Comment: It is really easy to shut off in Raspbian - a simple preference. But in Ubuntu they have kept it this way for a LONG time. Nobody has ever explained why. In any case, 6 years after this question was asked, it is now July 2017 and in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, this is the best you can do:   First, go to Appearances and set it so the menu will show up in the window title, then go to the File Manager and select Homes/  Press Alt-E then pick Preferences and there is an option there to turn on a Delete option under Move to Trash in the context menu of files or directories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a delete action as described at
[How to delete files bypassing trash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18863/how-to-delete-files-bypassing-trash) .
Files deleted from the console are immediately removed, but please note that under some circumstances they can still be recovered, if you want to securely delete files use the "wipe" command.

Comment: I just dont want to think about empting the trash, thx.

Comment: There is no option to disable the trash entirely, see bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/118988, what you can do is to enable the delete files option and remap the DEL key to invoke it. In practice this will disable the trash bin from the file manager.

Comment: Wont get rid of the trash from Unity Laucnher though

Comment: @KyleClarke Right. It's [currently not possible to remove Trash from the Unity launcher](http://askubuntu.com/a/80399/18612), as this is by design, and would require modifying Unity's source code and recompiling.

Answer (score 11):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> instead of <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete file(s) forever, but don't forget; If you delete the file forever, you can't easily get it back.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm.

```
Places->Home Folder->Edit->Preferences->Behavior->Include a Delete command [...]
```

Yes, console deletes have no "recycle" action - they are gone.

Answer (score 3):

On my mp3 player I added a file called `.Trash-1000` (not a directory), which just gets in the way.

I hit `Delete` and get prompted: *Cannot move file to rubbish, do you want to delete immeditately?* with the default action `Delete`.

Good enough for my needs.

Comment: You save my day! This doesn't remove the Trash feature.  Just create a **file** `.Trash-1000` to disable Trash.

Comment: Also, in ~/.local/share do similar: rm -rf Trash, then echo "nyah" >Trash

Answer (score 2):

You can set the immutable bit.

To do so, first empty the trash:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

And then:

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.local/share/Trash/
```

After that, when you delete or move something to the trash, you'll get the following message:

```
Cannot move to trash, delete it immediately?
```

---

**EDIT: Actual results below**

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /home/sg1/.local/share/Trash/
```

Comment: or just remove that directory then echo "nyah" >Trash

Answer (score 2):

The answer by SirCrow with the immutable bit might be better, but here's another alternative solution.  In my case, I solved it with:

```
sudo chown -R root:root ~/.local/share/Trash
```

This will change ownership of the location where the trashed files are typically stored to root, making the normal, non-root user unable to use the trash.  Of course, this assumes the current desktop user is not running as root, but typically that's not the case since it isn't recommended anyway.

When the Trash directory is owned by root in this way, you'll see the message:

```
Cannot move file to the bin, do you want to delete it immediately?
```

As was answered before, anything deleted from Terminal/Console is gone for good -- No trash.

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Well they all seem like pretty hacky options, but yours seems as good an answer as any of the previous ones IMHO. Kudos for a useful and well-explained first-answer and late-answer. It's pretty rare we see that around here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I too am one of those who have been bugged by this problem for a number of years ... unsatisfied with the existing proposals, I've recently taken the time to investigate a solution myself.

Starting with the premise that I want the Trash to be gone system-wide, I've found that -- for the time being -- the only real solution is to create a custom-compiled version of **libgio** (» [GIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software))) which is modified to call **g_file_delete()** every time an application calls **g_file_trash()**.

For all technology savvy users interested in this solution: I've just recently posted a step-by-step guide on *GitHub*:

[Globally disable GNOME's Trash in Debian-based distributions](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Cordic77/libgio-disable-trash/blob/master/Globally%20disable%20GNOME's%20Trash%20in%20Debian-based%20distributions.htm)

I hope this is of (some) help to those who hate the Trash with the same passion as I do ...

Answer (score 0):

For the external drives, remove any `/.Trash-$UID` directories.

For the current drive, as for the workaround, you can set Bin to automatically empty (e.g. every hour). To do that, go to *Activities* and type *File History & Trash* (part of *Settings*). From there you can adjust the *Rubbish Bin* settings. You can also find the steps how to get into Rubbish settings in Ubuntu's Help.