# How can I remove the Trash icon from the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I would like to not show the trash icon at the bottom of the Unity launcher.

Is this possible without having to recompile anything? :P

Comment: Are you using Unity2D? Then no compile is needed, compile is needed for Unity3D but its possible (and not complicated). Drop a comment if you are still interested.

Comment: I'm interested in removing the trash icon.

Comment: This thing is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the desktop interface, the Dash icon and the Trash icon use the top and bottom slots of the launcher, always. We have not allowed the removal of the Trash so that we can enable developers to trust that it will always be there, which means "drag to the trash" is always possible.

It might be worth considering relaxing the requirement that the trash always be on the bottom corner, allowing other icons to take that spot. A blueprint to that effect, discussing the consequences and solutions to issues that might arise, would be welcome.

Comment: My personal experience (on Windows, as well as Ubuntu) is that if something isn't there that the documentation "trusts" is there, then I remember that the reason is that I removed it, and there is no problem. I'd like to remove the trash icon, perhaps even with a strong warning.

Comment: Ouch ouch ouch.  I get the rationale, and hate the placement.  One of my four most accessible corners of my screen, taken over by something that I have the delete key for anyway.

Comment: Why would a program need to drag something, anyway?  A robot program should be hitting the delete key if it wants to delete something, not dragging it to the trash, the same way real users hit the delete key, rather than dragging to the trash.

Comment: It's unbelievable that now a days this thing persists. It's pointless not get ride of this functionality.

Comment: I like unity launcher at the left, but for some reason, i always end up click unintentionally in the trash button. Maybe my fingers are too big. Anyways, i wish i could remove that button. Sometimes i'm in the middle of an important work and "appear" the trash foler...

Answer (score 5):

Currently it's not possible. You should start a blueprint for this in Launchpad, so we can see it in future versions of Unity.

Comment: AFAIK, I was able to remove the Trash Icon in Unity 2D, why is it that it doesn't work in regular Unity?

Comment: @Madhava: Did you remove the trash icon by [modifying Launcher.qml](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2011/02/remove-and-rearrange-items-in-unity-2d.html)? That file doesn't exist for Unity. I guess the configuration is totally different?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to **visually** make the trash icon **disappear**. The icon will still spatially be there. Make backups of the icon image if desired.

- Open a terminal.
- type `sudo -H nautilus`
- press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- type "trash" into the search bar
- There will be many pictures of the trash (full or empty) icon with the `.svg` extension. Select the second largest version of the trash icon and open it with inkscape.
- Press select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and then press the <kbd>delete</kbd>key on your keyboard. Save and exit.
- Do the same thing for the empty version/full version if you
  have not already.
- Reboot your computer.

You should then see that the trash icon has visually disappeared and if you mouse over its usual location at the bottom of the launcher, a flag should pop up saying "Trash" or "Empty trash" as usual.