# Location of trash icon in Unity Launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, trash

After I boot my laptop, I see a 'space' between `Workspace Switcher` and `Trash` on the launcher. This is the screenshot:

[image: Trash location]

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think it is not a bug. By default the arrangement of trash is as you shown in screen shot.

Comment: That's what I remember as well. The Trash bin stays at the bottom of the launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the design of Unity Launcher, Trash icon stays at the bottom. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/80399/58990) is an answer explaining the rationale. This is not a bug, but a design feature.