# How to suppress the Log Out confirmation dialog?

Tags: logout

Ubuntu Unity Panel includes menu items **Lock** and **Log Out**. But when you click **Log Out**, you see a dialog box asking if you'd like to **Lock** or **Log Out** (a Microsoft-style question for dummies ;-) which I find annoying.

Opening **dconf Editor** and selecting **org > gnome > gnome-session** and disabling **logout-prompt** has no effect, unlike selecting **apps > indicator-session** and enabling **suppress-logout-restart-shutdown**, which does what it says -- getting rid of a similar question.

Comment: `org.gnome.gnome-session` is for Gnome stuff - I would try under `com.canonical.Unity` *(or whatever it is - don't have access to unity at the moment)*

Comment: Because Unity is based on Gnome, I thought it should work. Perhaps we should wait until developers care to add such an option to **apps > indicator-session** then???

Comment: Depends - with Unity (and some bits of gnome) they seem to prefer what they want over what the users want (e.g. [the trash icon](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37776/how-can-i-remove-the-trash-icon-from-the-unity-launcher)). Note you may also be able [log out via terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15795/how-can-you-log-out-via-the-terminal), and could assign a shortcut to it. [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020630) may also help. It may also be available as a option under Compiz or something... what version of Unity + Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I use Ubuntu 14.10 with Unity 7.3.1. There's no such option in Compiz Unity Settings. But it's possible to log out bypassing that odd dialog merely by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+Back**. And this seems the best alternative to using the current Log Out menu item at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such option yet (as of Ubuntu 16.10).

But it is possible to log out directly by using the keyboard shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Back</kbd>.