# Is there a way to make the Delete-key bypass Trash in MATE/Caja?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, delete, trash, caja

On Windows systems, the Trash-folder for deleted files can be turned off in the system settings, making a simple <kbd>Delete</kbd> keypress remove the selected file(s) permanently.

I know that it's possible to directly delete files on both Ubuntu and Windows with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, however besides being confusing when coming from the aforementioned Windows config, this is not possible to use if there is any second-layer keymapping on the Delete-key.

Is there a way to have a single Delete keypress permanently remove files in the Caja file manager?

Comment: Not without changing source code, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've looked through the other solutions and found this workaround:
[How to turn off trash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20500/how-to-turn-off-trash/46636#46636)

It suggests to remove everything in `~/.local/share/Trash/` and then make the directory immutable by setting it to `sudo chattr +i ~/.local/share/Trash/` in the command line. In my case, I had to create the `Trash` directory first, because I had never moved anything there.

In MATE/Caja, I get an error message that the Trash directory could not be modified when I try to normally delete something. Then I can hit Enter on the dialog box to delete the file permanently. This practically works like the Windows option, so it is a functional solution for me.

I tried this on Thunar as well, but it didn't give me an option to permanently delete the file, it just shows an error message.

I don't use Thunar a lot so this is not relevant for me, but *ymmv* depending on the file manager. I've changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### Show Action to Permanently Delete Files and Folders

At the top of the page, when Files/Nautilus is open, select Files, then select Preferences, then select Behavior, then select Show action to permanently delete files and folders.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't actually provide what OP asked for. It just adds one extra context menu (right-click menu) item to delete without using the trash, it *does not* let the user remove a file bypassing the trash *by pressing the <Delete> key*. But nevertheless it may be useful workaround.

Comment: @Pomsky: Seems almost as fast to left click the file and click Delete Permanently as left clicking and hit Delete. It is the best I know.

Comment: The question is specifically on hitting the Delete key and have it bypass the trash, so indeed, your answer is useful as a workaround, yet does not answer the question. The answer is, a.f.a.i.k., that it used to be possible in the old days, but not anymore in current versions of nautilus.