# how to completely delete some files on an external drive by using Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, external-hdd, filemanager, permanent-delete

My Windows 8.1 doesn't boot anymore, so I want do a backup of the files contained on Windows to an external hard disk by using an Ubuntu live distro.

Before doing that I need more free space on the external drive **without formatting it**, so I'm trying to delete some files and folders. When I delete them, they don't appear anymore but the size of the free space on the external disk doesn't change.

When I deleted a larger folder, a message said it was too large and would be deleted permanently, and then the size of the free space in the external disk increased.

For I need more free space on the externaal disk, I suppose I should look for a Recycle Bin and clear its content...

Where may I find this Recycle Bin on the external drive (to completely delete the selected files) from Linux?

Comment: You did not specify how you deleted them ;-)  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/34296/why-does-deleting-a-file-on-a-usb-stick-not-free-up-space  if done with Nautilus. There might be a ".Trash" in the root directory BUT when removing from command line there is not trash involved. removed = gone. If from a desktop: use shift-delete That will skip the bin too ;)

Comment: Ok then press control-h on the highest dir on the external disk and see the .Trash/ directory. There it'll be.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you delete files on a usb drive they get put in a hidden file .trash or something like that. Do a `ls -a` on the usb drive and see what hidden files there are. If there is a .trash do a `rm -rf` to that file.

If you are navigating to the directory from the gui you should be able to right click and select "open in terminal" and execute the `ls -a` and `rm -rf "filename"` from the terminal that way. Sometimes its easier to navigate via gui than try and get to a mounted usb drive.