# Why is a .Trash-1000 hidden folder created when I try to delete files from a mounted MicroSD card?

Tags: mount, delete, trash, sd-card

I have recently been mounting my Android phone via a USB cable and have been adding and deleting files to the microSD card. However I noticed that space was not being freed up when I deleted files. It took a while to work out that whenever I delete a file they are actually being moved to a hidden folder on the card called .Trash-1000

Is this normal behaviour? I guess Ubuntu is creating some kind of recycle bin on the SD card? And if it is normal behaviour is there a way to disable this function/delete files without them being placed in the .Trash-1000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it is normal if you want to delete it forever, use

<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>delete</kbd>

**Linked questions**

1. [Why does deleting a file on a USB stick not free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34296/why-does-deleting-a-file-on-a-usb-stick-not-free-up-space)
2. [How to delete files bypassing trash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18863/how-to-delete-files-bypassing-trash/18864#18864)