# Is it possible to delete the trash folder?

Tags: directory, trash

"Chuck Norris can delete the Recycling Bin."

I found this Chuck Norris joke, and, being a Linux user (admit it, we are all convinced that Linux users can, in theory, do anything on their computer) immediately wondered if this is possible. I found an article on deleting the recycle bin in Windows (even though the system will recreate it), which for me simply confirms that it must be possible in Linux as well ;D. Please note that I have no practical use for this, I'm just wondering if it's possible. Also note that there is a big distinction here: I am NOT asking how to empty the trash, I'm asking how to delete the location that trashed files go to.

Comment: Trash folder is located at `/home/$USER/.local/share/`, it will recreate itself if file is moved to trash and Trash folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Where do you want trashed files to go? The question is not clear about your (hypothetical) intent.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/18866/15811 :)

Comment: I don't really want to delete the trash. I'm really just wondering from a "let's nerd out about linux" standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Install Gnome Tweaks from the Ubuntu Software Center and navigate to Desktop and set Wastebasket to OFF.

This hides the icon from the desktop but doesn't delete the location where trashed files are sent to [`~/.local/share/Trash`] which will automatically be regenerated by the system if not present.

[image]

So, a workaround to avoid deleted files even reaching there is to simply use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> when deleting files.

Comment: Nice answer but ***I'm asking how to delete the location that trashed files go to.*** 1st part of your answer is telling how to hide icon from desktop and 2nd part, how to delete files permanently which I think doesn't address above statement properly.

Comment: @Kulfy I think you answered that in your comment to the OPs post but sometimes encouraging people to mess with the system can end in tears. It's regenerated for a reason but there is a suitable workaround. Out of sight out of mind, as they say.

Comment: Yeah but IMO this is not messing anything since we know what we are doing, why and aftermath. I think you should include these things in your answer.

Comment: @Kulfy included as suggested for a more complete answer, thanks

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @Kulfy. I agree that actually deleting the trash folder is probably not smart, I was just curious as to where it actually was and whether Linux even would let me delete it. I appreciate your concern, however.